# Button actions on dynamically created kivy widgets

Tags: python, events, kivy, grid-layout

I am dynamically creating rows in the add_row function that get added to this scroll view list and it all looks/works very nicely. The problem is the rows have buttons and I want those buttons to have events/actions bound to them. I tried putting the on_release, but it throws this error:

```
File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 419, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.bind
 AssertionError: None is not callable
```

I don't know how to make it so I can bind the button to something while still keeping the dynamic structure. Please help! Here is my code:

```
def add_row(self, profile, user_id, user_name, percent):
    layout = GridLayout(rows=1, row_force_default=True, row_default_height=60)
    layout.add_widget(ImageButton(source=profile))
    layout.add_widget(Label(text="@" + user_name, color=(0, 0, 0, 1), font_size=20))
    layout.add_widget(Label(text=str(user_id), color=(0, 0, 0, 0), font_size=20))
    bsplit = GridLayout(rows=1)
    bsplit.add_widget(Button(background_normal='images/buttonbackgrounds/unfollow.png',
                             background_down='images/buttonbackgrounds/unfollow_select.png', size_hint_x=None, width=100, id=str(user_id), on_release=self.unfollow()))
    bsplit.add_widget(Button(background_normal='images/buttonbackgrounds/waitlist.png',
                             background_down='images/buttonbackgrounds/waitlist_select.png', size_hint_x=.5, border=(3,3,3,3), id=str(user_id)))
    layout.add_widget(bsplit)
    self.ids.widget_list.add_widget(layout)
    self.update_percent(percent)

def unfollow(self):
    print(self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [bind](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.event.html#kivy.event.EventDispatcher.bind) for that.

```py
    button1 = Button(background_normal='images/buttonbackgrounds/unfollow.png',
                     background_down='images/buttonbackgrounds/unfollow_select.png',
                     size_hint_x=None, width=100, id=str(user_id))
    button1.bind(on_release=self.unfollow)
    bsplit.add_widget(button1)
```

Notice that you just pass the method object to the `bind`, not executing it by using the "()".